# Replacing value in list gives error message: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to replace every '-1' in my list (containing 370 lines with different numbers of rows) to the value '0'.

My list looks like that: 
[image: list example]

I tried that code:

```
for (idx, item) in enumerate(expression_list):
    if item == -1:
        expression_list[idx] = 0

and it gives me the error message:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Each *item* in *expression_list* is a list of its own. Use another loop, if you want to go in this path.

Comment: I tried `for l in enumerate(expression_list):
    for (idx, item) in enumerate(l):
        if item == -1:
            expression_list[idx] = 0` but it returns exactly the same error message..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each *item* is a list on its own, and not just a value, so python is saying it can't determine that the list is or is not a value.
Anyway, it's better to use list comprehension:

```
expression_list = [[x if x != -1 else 0 for x in item] for item in expression_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problem is that you do not use enumerate correctly. Your code is equivalent to :

```
for item in expression_list:
    # print("What is in item ? {}".format(item))
    if item == -1:
        item = 0
```

You can now see more clearly that `item` is actually a whole row (a list) and not the value you want. So you probably need something like this:

```
for row in expression_list:
    if row[3] == -1:
        row[3] = 0
```

Comment: Yes the first one is equivalent, you need to access the right value, right now you have a list, you need to access a specific element inside the list (see seecond snippet).